# Passing None as Null to MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I have sample:

```
args["test"] = None

try:
  with self.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
  cursor.callproc('mystoredproc',[str(args["test"])])
  self.connection.commit()
  result = {"status": True, "reason": "", "result": json.loads(json.dumps(cursor.fetchone(), cls=DateTimeEncoder))}
except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
  print("ERROR: {}".format(e))
  result = {"status": False, "reason": "Insert Failed", "result": "ERROR: {}".format(e)}
finally:
  # self.DestroyConnection()
  pass
```

question is simple:

how do i pass None as null above?
is it possible without converting the value?

bacause if i run that code it will return me:

> ERROR: (1366, "Incorrect decimal value: 'None' for column 'test' at
>   row 1")

which it suppose to set the value as NULL in DB

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but if `str()` casts to string then surely you're attempting to insert `'None'` rather than `None`.

Comment: are you using `pymysql` for making mysql connection?

Comment: @eggyal, ohh my,,, how dumb am I -.-! you are right! thanks man ! :D